# Binding DataGrid to an ObservableCollection which is a property of a ListBox's SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listbox, polymorphism

In my application I have a `ListBox` and a `DataGrid`.

I'm trying to bind the `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection` which is a property of the returned `SelectedItem` from the `ListBox` - this doesn't work and I don't understand why. Output console doesn't print any errors.

The `ObservableCollection` is of type `ReportItem`, and it can contain instances of `TextReportItem`, which inherits from `ReportItem`.

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,36.667" Width="119" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportItems}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox> 
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="274" Margin="134,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" >
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 10, 0, 0" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataGrid Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.TItems}" />
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ReportItem> ReportItems { get; set; }
    public object SelectedReportItem { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ReportItems = new ObservableCollection<ReportItem>();
        ReportItems.Add(Example);
    }
    // line below is for debugging purposes
    public TextReportItem Example = new TextReportItem() { Name = "ti1", DataFile = "ti1.txt"};
}
```

`ReportItem`:

```
public class ReportItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataFile { get; set; }
}
```

`TextReportItem` and `TextParcel`:

```
public class TextReportItem : ReportItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextParcel> TItems { get; set; }
    public TextReportItem()
    {
        TItems = new ObservableCollection<TextParcel>();
    }
}
public class TextParcel
{
    public char Delimiter { get; set; }
    public string LineExp { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string IgnoreLine { get; set; }
    public int DesiredResultIndexInLine { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mere DataContext doesn't tell the DataGrid what it has to show. You have to give it an ItemsSource. Maybe you could try something like that:

```
<DataGrid 
     DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding TItems}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the DataContext of a DataGrid expects an IEnumerable, and not a single instance of an object. When you set the source to a single instance of a ReportItem, you're not passing it anything that it can iterate to construct it's rows.

If you make the necessary changes and give that a yank, you should be golden :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use select index change method instead

```
    protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
string value = null;
value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text.ToString();
}
```